# Refreshing Data Source, then Pivot Table

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel workbook that is being used to summarize 11 other workbooks. I have about 30 queries that connect to tables in these other workbooks, then an append query to join them all together.

I am trying to make a macro to update the underlying data (my queries and append table), and then push it into a pivot table for reporting. I wanted to make a single button that would update everything for my user, however, when I try to update the data and pivot table together I have found that the Pivot Table does not want to update.

```
Sub DataLoad()
    If MsgBox("Are you sure that you wish to update all of the data? This will take a minute", vbYesNo, "Confirm") = vbYes Then
    'Refresh Data
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    End If
End Sub

Sub DataUpdate()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        'Refresh Pivot Table
        Range("F9").Select
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh

        'MsgBox "Data update complete!"
        Call Formatting    
End Sub
```

I began trying to perform the "ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll" command and updating the pivot table in a single sub, but if I did that the Pivot table would not update. The only way I found I could get the pivot table to update was to separate the two actions and perform them completely separately. I have also tried calling the 'DataUpdate' action inside 'DataLoad' to no success.

I believe that it is trying to perform both actions at once. Does anyone know of a method so I can ensure my DataLoad finishes and only then will perform the DataUpdate?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the Pivot is on the Active Sheet?

Comment: I just tried adding Sheets(Name).activate before calling DataUpdate and had the same result.